# Any Alternative fix for printing a webpage when designed with vmin/vmax/vw/vh-font-sized texts

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, viewport-units

So i am working on a fluid responsive design and the text size on the website works based on %. 
Just realized that if i try to print(cmd+p) the website design breaks on chrome. 
Looks like a pretty old and known issue and was not able to find a hack online to make this work?
Can you please suggest something on this?

Issue mentioned here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=382313
Here is the html you can try putting on a local html page and try printing on chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .vmin {
    font-size: 10vmin;
}

.px {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.vw {
    font-size: 10vw;
}

.vh {
    font-size: 10vh;
}

.box {
    width: 10vw;
    height: 10vh;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="vmin">
    using vmin - font-size: 10vmin;
</div>
<div class="px">
    using px - font-size: 20px;
</div>
<div class="vw">
    using vw - font-size: 10vw;
</div>
<div class="vh">
    using vh - font-size: 10vh;
</div>
<div class="box">
    inside box - box size: 10vw x 10vh;
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also was thing if there is a way i can pass a view size hardcoded when the print is called?

Answer (score 1):

```
<style media="screen">
.vmin {
    font-size: 10vmin;
}

.px {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.vw {
    font-size: 10vw;
}

.vh {
    font-size: 10vh;
}

.box {
    width: 10vw;
    height: 10vh;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>

<style media="print">
        /* Here be CSS applied exclusively when the page is printed */
</style>
```

http://htmldog.com/references/html/tags/style/